# ¿como puedo dibujar mi propia ruta en google maps?

Tags: google-maps

quisiera saber si es posible trazar mi propia ruta en google maps, no con un polilyne, sino una ruta como la que muestra cuando voy de un punto A a un punto B de la ciudad. o mediante algún otro API de mapas, de manera que pueda usar la señal de un GPS externo para trazar la misma.

si hay alguna documentación que pueda ser de ustilidad, un curso o cualquier tipo de recurso, sería muy útil.
gracias y espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Si escribes en github "trace route google maps" encontrarás mucho material para lo que pides. Esta pregunta te la cerrarán. Te recomiendo leer esto sobre como preguntar: (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) saludos.

Comment: Si no quieres usar una polilínea sino un directions renderer, tienes una cantidad máxima de paradas intermedias que puedes poner. Esto significa que no puedes seguir la ruta exacta que te vaya marcando el GPS a menos que empieces a descartar puntos intermedios